# After selecting an item from dropdown, display new options and show text?

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is, have a dropdown list that when you click on a selection, the selection will load new options depending on what you clicked on and as well show text or an image below what you have selected. The only real way I can explain it is with a pic I created.

image link here: http://aionhg.com/images/jsq.png
(I cant post images as I am a new user, understandable)

I have been trying to figure it out in JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrRZj/1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
    function setFieldValue() {
        var currentVal = $("#Copiers option:selected").val();
        $("#field1").val(currentVal);

        if (currentVal == "2000") {
            $("#img1").replaceWith("<div id='img1'><img src='http://tinyurl.com/d7xeuph'></div>");
        } else {
            $("#img1").replaceWith("<div id='img1'></div>");
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrRZj/3/

Hope this helps.